# Clientside Performance Tests for Hybrid App

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, mobile-applications

I am using JMeter for testing the server side performance of our Mobile App.

What tool can I use to test the client side performance of the app?

I know there is a plug in for JMeter but as far as I am concerned what can be used for Mobile Apps?

Answer (score 1):

From your description of the question it would seem that you want to do *Load/Stress/Volume testing* of the mobile application.

For that you use **Jmeter** or **apptim** (I haven't used this personally so won't comment on it) as suggested by ***Kalei***, or any other tool that others might suggest.

But, when talking about performance testing why would you limit yourself to only hitting multiple requests (*Load/Stress/Volume etc testing*)? This would only test the load your server can handle or the interaction between your application and the server. It won't test how the application itself performs on the device.

There's a lot more to mobile application's performance testing. Here are a few things you can test as part of performance testing,

1. Whether it works in the same seamless manner on a phone with low hardware, OS and memory configurations as it does on a phone with high memory and hardware or does it hang or get slow.
2. How much battery does it consume? How much memory and CPU does it occupy?
3. Does it get slow if used for a long time?
4. Does it maintain a local database on the phone? If yes, does it get slow with increase in size of the database?
5. If it requires internet connection how well does it work with slow network connections like 2G/3G or bad WIFI?
6. Have few applications open in background and then try to run your application. Does it hang or get slow?
7. And so on...

Answer (score 0):

**Check out [Apptim](https://apptim.com/#utm_source=stackexchange&utm_content=answer).** It was designed specifically for client side performance of native apps and can work for hybrid as well.

This is a good article that explains how to run a test with Apptim and can give you an idea if it is the right fit: https://blog.apptim.com/mobile-performance-testing/

Disclaimer, I work there as a product marketer, but I really do feel that this solution will be useful to you.